# Generate default value in EF Core Cosmos

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

In my Cosmos database, I have a property `CreatedAt` which is a `DateTime`. I want the value to be generated automatically upon insert.

In my `OnModelCreating` method I've tried the following without any success:

- `modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(p => p.CreatedAt).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();`
- `modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(p => p.CreatedAt).HasDefaultValueSql("getdate()");`
- `modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(p => p.CreatedAt).HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now);`

Looking in Cosmos DB Emulator, this property is always set to the default DateTime value. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  I am seeing the same for an `int` property - it fails because there is no value set.

Comment: Only for the CreatedAt and UpdatedAt by using the ChangeTracker from DbContext and enumerating addedEntities and UpdatedEntities